# Find the length of the longer diagonal on a trapezium with only 2 sides stated.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Im at a loss here, i know i have to divide the trapezium, but im still not sure which calculation is relevant to it then. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: first of all, that's not a rhombus, and secondly, do you want that value depending on the angle x? Because there's no unique solution to this problem

Comment: There isn't enough information (unless the marking at $D$ indicates that $\angle BDC$ is right).

Comment: A trapezium, sorry. The question below it contained rhombus.

I drew that in, but it wasn't proportional to a right angle so I'm guessing its not.  Ill speak to my tutor as i felt there was insufficient information supplied too.